# Calculating conditional summaries of grouped data in dplyr

Tags: r

I have a dataset of population mortality data segregated by year, decile (ranked) of deprivation, gender, cause of death and age. Age data is broken down into categories including 0-1, 1-4, 5-9, 10-14 etc.

I am trying to coerce my dataset such that the mortality data for 0-1 and 1-4 is merged together to create age categories 0-4, 5-9, 10-14 and so on up to 90. My data is in long format.

Using dplyr I am trying to use if_else and summarise() to aggregate mortality data for 0-1 and 1-4 together, however any iteration of code I apply is merely producing the same dataset I originally had, i.e. the code is not merging my data together.

```
head(death_popn_long) #cause_death variable content removed for brevity

Year deprivation_decile  Sex cause_death ageband deaths popn
1 2017                  1 Male          NA       0      0 2106
2 2017                  1 Male          NA       0      0 2106
3 2017                  1 Male          NA       0      0 2106
4 2017                  1 Male          NA       0      0 2106
5 2017                  1 Male          NA       0      0 2106
6 2017                  1 Male          NA       0      0 2106

#Attempt to merge ageband 0-1 & 1-4 by summarising combined death counts

test <- death_popn_long %>% 
group_by(Year, deprivation_decile, Sex, cause_death, ageband) %>%
summarise(deaths = if_else(ageband %in% c("0", "1"), sum(deaths), 
deaths))
```

I would like the deaths variable to be the combined (i.e. sum of both 0-1 and 1-4) death count for these age bands, however the above any any alternative code I attempt merely recreates the previous dataset I already had.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `ageband` in your `group_by` statement if you intend on manipulating its groups. You'll need to create your new version of `ageband` and then group by that:

```
test <- death_popn_long %>% 
    mutate(new_ageband = if_else(ageband %in% c("0", "1"), 1, ageband)) %>%
    group_by(Year, deprivation_decile, Sex, cause_death, new_ageband) %>%
    summarise(deaths = sum(deaths))
```

If you'd like a marginally shorter version you can define `new_ageband` in the `group_by` clause instead of using a `mutate` verb beforehand. I just did that to be explicit.

Also, for future SO questions - it's very helpful to provide data in your question (using something like `dput`). :)

Comment: Thank you so much Zack that works perfectly. Will endeavour in future to provide data as suggested.

Comment: No problem, if this did in fact answer your question, feel free to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Enjoy your analyses!